# What is the use of "accept rate"

Tags: support

When you ask a question I see under your rep it posts your % accept rate. What is this used for? I think some people may feel put off answering a question if the person asking has a low acceptance rate. Is it to encourage people to remember to mark answers as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accept rate is a measure for the percentage of questions that are marked as answer.
It is ment as you mention as an encouragement to people to mark the answer that was most useful as an answer.
Read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I would also tend to think people answering your questions might shy away if they don't think you are going to actually select an answer eventually.